# How to set a field parameter inside resolver

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem to limit my graphql endpoint to only serve data the requesting user is allowed to request

I'm using

```
apollo-server 2.1.0
express 4.16.3
graphql 0.13.2
graphql-tools 4.0.0
neo4j-graphql-js 0.2.1
```

The type **Tag** has a field **elements** which should only contain the elements the current user owns.

```
type Tag {
  name: String!
  elements(username:String): [Element] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (this)-[:TAGGED]-(e:Element)-[:OWNER]-(u:User) WHERE u.name=$username RETURN e")
}

type Element {
  uuid: String!
  name: String
  users: [User] @relation(name:"OWNER", direction:"IN")
  tags: [Tag] @relation(name:"TAGGED", direction:"IN")
  responses: [Element] @relation(name:"RESPONSE", direction:"OUT")
}
```

When my query looks like:

```
{
Tag{
    name,
    elements(username:"crmue"){
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks like expected. But I want to check and set the username argument within the resolver based on the context attached user.

But when I add the following line to the Tag root resolver before the query gets executed, my response is empty.

```
params['username'] = ctx.user.name;
```

In this case the generated cypher statement places the username agrument to root Tag section and not to child Element (@cypher statement) section. But I have no idea how to set the username argument for the Tag field elements within the resolver, before the data are getting fetched.

So I hope someone has maybe an idea how to solve my problem or has a better idea than my solution here with the @cypher statement.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

My current basic resolvers are:

```
export const resolvers = {

  Tag : {
    elements : (object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) => {
      params["username"] = ctx.user.name;

    }
  },

  Query: {
    User(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
      return neo4jgraphql(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo);
    },
    Element(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
      return neo4jgraphql(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo);
    },

    Tag(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
      if(!ctx.user){
       throw Error("Wrong request");
      }
      params["username"] = ctx.user.name;
      return neo4jgraphql(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo); 
    },

  }
};
```

Adding the param within a 'elements' field resolver has no effect, since the field resolvers are called when the data are already fetched.

Comment: use `ctx.user.name` directly in `elements` resolver?

Comment: I tried that but the the field resolvers are called when the data are already fetched. I can use the `element` resolver to filter the fetched data afterafterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually root resolver doesn't return the whole object, only 'own fields' leaving related fields to be processed by fields resolvers. In this case it looks like `neo4jgraphql` (I'm guessing, I didn't use it) is smart enough to process it entirely at the root level.

If `params["username"] = ctx.user.name;` in `Tag` doesn't work then it looks like `neo4jgraphql` doesn't care about `params` (IMHO it should - issue?) and works directly on resolver `info` argument (already existing variables).

Try to add `username` into `variableValues` array. [Explanations](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a/)
 Field resolver shouldn't be required in this case.

Second option: remove `elements` from `fieldNodes` (in `Tag` resolver) and use field resolver (params/variableValues).

If still in trouble check/log `info` state/values.

Comment: neo4j-graphql-js tries to fetch everything in one round trip to the database within the root Tag resolver. The `@cypher` directive of field `elements` is used to build this single cypher statement. I solved my problem with your advise to modify the argument values within the relover info. It's not really convenient but it works.

Comment: Created an issue on github for neo4j-graphql-js see [issue link #112](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js/issues/112)